# SQLAlchemy relationship introspection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, introspection

I have two mapped classes with a one-to-many relation:

```
class Part(...):
    product = relationship('products', backref=backref('parts'))

class Product(...):
    pass
```

Given `Part.product`, I can introspect this relationship, namely get the attribute name, and also get the backref attribute name:

```
>>> rel = Part.product   # image it's passed in as a function parameter
>>> rel.property.key
'product'
>>> rel.property.backref[0]
'parts'
```

I can also access the relationship the other way round:

```
>>> rel = Product.parts
>>> rel
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x3744fd0>
>>> rel.property.key
'parts'
```

However, I cannot find out how to access the original attribute name (aka the backref' backref attribute, aka 'product' in the example):

```
>>> rel.property.backref is None
True
```

Where do I have to tickle `Product.parts` to obtain `'product'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce situation your described and got `Product.parts.property.backref = None` too.
After debugging in pycharm I found that other property holds the name of property in parts:

```
print Product.parts.property.backref
>>>None
print Product.parts.property.back_populates
>>>product
```

I would suggest to consider using `back_populates` in this case as a hack.

back_populates is described in [documentation Linking Relationship Configuration:Relationships with Backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html). According to documentation you would need to define your model like that:

```
class Part(...):
    product = relationship('products', back_populates='parts')

class Product(...):
    parts = relationship('products', back_populates='product')
    pass
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I need :-) I don't even consider this a hack, it looks like the canonical way to look up the attribute name (backref being a shortcut to set back_populates). Thank you for figuring that out!